Upgraded Spring 5.3.10 app from Java 8 to Java 11, getting RuntimeException
Getting following error when upgrading spring 5.3.10 java 8 application to java 11:
2024-05-31 10:55:22.720:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@61a87366{/appdiscoveryAdminService,file:///D:/XVP/Fresh%20start/tsp_service-main2/tsp_service-main/angularAdminService/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///D:/XVP/Fresh%20start/tsp_service-main2/tsp_service-main/angularAdminService/src/main/webapp/}
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file Acl.class
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:732)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:709)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:850)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:462)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:979)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:725)

tried exclding old asm transient dependencies and included latest version as follows in pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
            <version>9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>9.1</version>
        </dependency>


I'm assuming that you simply installed Java 11 on your machine then tried to restart your app. If so then it will not work since you need to recompile your app using a Java 11 compiler or you won't be able to run the Java 8 build since they are not compatible.
You didn't provide any sample code or sufficient details on what steps you executed to perform the upgrade so contributors have to make a lot of assumptions as it's very difficult to provide a meaningful answer.
Feel free to edit your post with additional information. If you need guidance, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!
